# Laravel website not getting connected (Database connection failed)

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and currently working on a Laravel project.

When I used the 'php artisan serve' in my file to check whether if it is working/localhost , I am getting this error:

> (1/1) HttpException
> Database connection failed!
>
> in Application.php line 1014
>
> at Application->abort('399', 'Database connection failed!', array())in
> helpers.php line 46
>
> at abort('399', 'Database connection failed!')in ScriptMint.php line
> 31
>
> at ScriptMint->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php
> line 171
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))in
> XSSProtection.php line 33
>
> at XSSProtection->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in
> Pipeline.php line 171
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))in
> TransformsRequest.php line 21
>
> at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in
> Pipeline.php line 171
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))in
> ValidatePostSize.php line 27
>
> at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in
> Pipeline.php line 171
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))in
> CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 62
>
> at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in
> Pipeline.php line 171
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))in
> TrustProxies.php line 57
>
> at TrustProxies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in
> Pipeline.php line 171
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))in
> Pipeline.php line 105
>
> at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))in Kernel.php line 151
>
> at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))in Kernel.php line
> 116
>
> at Kernel->handle(object(Request))in index.php line 55
>
> at
> require_once('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\website\public\index.php')in
> server.php line 21

Comment: See your ".env" file, is the credentials correctly set against a local database?

Comment: ...and is the database server up and running?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.env` file in your project root directory.
It should have entries like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=<yourdatabase>
DB_USERNAME=<yourdatabaseuser>
DB_PASSWORD=<yourdatabaseuserpassword>
```

Also check in the `config` folder in the file `database.php`, if everything fits in your selected connection. Here an example from my `database.php`. I did not change anything here from the initial project setup:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: can anyone tell me how to local host and check, because i just wanted to check how does it look,when it is localhosted on XAMPP.Can you please tell what all are the changes to be made and where should i make the changes

Answer (score 0):

You have to create .env file inside root folder of your laravel installation.

Add this code to your .env file and change DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD to your database credentials.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:cqFZ1xZXorL2iw/2m6CDH676fyLT+CdmOOBNUIo7tSs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravelDb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```